# How to post angular object to MVC controller with a form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to angularjs.

I want post an angular object to a controller using a form.

Angular Controller:

```
$scope.PostObject = function(angularObject) {

    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.action = '/controller/action';
    form.method = 'POST';

    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.name = "angularObject";
    input.value = angularObject;

    form.appendChild(input);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();

};
```

MVC Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Action(MVCModel angularObject)
 {
    //do something then return action result

    return View(angularObject);

 }
```

Thanks for your help, if more details are needed let me know.

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want post an angular object

Use the $http service:

```
$http.post("/controller/action", angularObject);
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. So I tried using the http.post method. When I debug the controller the object gets passed fine. The controller returns the view. But then the page doesn't navigate there. This is why I was trying to use the form as it will navigate to a new page.

Comment: Forms do not POST JavaScript objects. They use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is problematic for JavaScript objects. The best for objects is `application/json` which is the default for the $http service.

Comment: Thanks again. I suppose my question now becomes how do I navigate to the View returned by my c# controller using this post request?

Comment: For performance, SPA frameworks like AngularJS avoid full page reloads. Since the role of forms in client-side AngularJS applications is different than in classical roundtrip apps, it is desirable for the browser not to translate the form submission into a full page reload.

Comment: Okay. Back to the drawing board I think! Cheers georgeawg.